# docker: error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com Forbidden

Tags: docker, proxy, cloudflare

When I run:

```
docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
2db29710123e: Pulling fs layer
docker: error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/fe/feb5d8asdf678asd9fsdf7a9sd6f789sa6d7f8b825965ba48de054caab5ef356dc6b3412/data?verify=161234117-fZrnvGSb678afASf87g7dfd7InfY%3D: Forbidden.
```

I am running docker from behind a proxy and have done the following setup:
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/

I have found this for the error, which states that the IP is blocked by Cloudflare and nothing can be done https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-pull-image-from-docker-hub-forbidden/27376/2 ?

Is there any solution to the `Forbidden` error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Forbidden` error occurs if the url is is not accessible, in this case `https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/`.

All the below urls have to be whitelisted behind a proxy / firewall.

- https://auth.docker.io
- https://registry-1.docker.io
- https://production.cloudflare.docker.com

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this happens when you're trying to request for an image multiple times, so if this continues trying using a VPN application, so that you can produce a new IP and bypass that issue. Is just a common thing with cloudflare. So in this case a vpn can help you for the mean time.